# URL not working without /wordpress/ at the end of it

Tags: php, wordpress, web-config, subdomain

I'm having some problems with a subdomain that i activated using godaddy hosting!
everything seems to work fine, except for the domain itself, I can't access my subdomain using http://sierranortesevilla.tritton.es i get a 500 error, i have to access from http://sierranortesevilla.tritton.es/wordpress 
i tried changing the siteURL from WordPress setting but nothing, i still get that error!
what should I do? Have I done something wrong?

PS: WordPress is installed in a subdirectory, I actually have two WordPress installations: one for the primary domain and tha other for the subdomain
PS2: I'm using Godaddy hosting Under Windows

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you followed all the instructions given in the WordPress documentation about installing WordPress in a folder but using it for root access?

Details can be found [HERE](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install)

You pretty much have to just copy and paste the `index.php` and `.htaccess` file into the root and then change the url's in the `index.php`, `wp-config.php` and also the admin settings & permanlinks page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did what you said and the subdomain works now without /WordPress/ but i don't have access to my Dashboard anymore!i get the same 500 error whan i try get in the Dashboard to update permalinks!

Comment: you still have to access /WordPress/wp-admin/ and not just root/wp-admin/

Comment: Have you completed step 7 correctly? And have you made sure to copy and paste instead of move the files?

Comment: I wasn't able to, since I couldn't access the Dashboard to update permalinks. and I don't know how to manually change web.config (i don't have (.htaccess)! and YES I copied the files i didn't move them!

Comment: the web.config file you should be able to access with notepad. If you run notepad as an administrator and then find the web.config file in your filestructure, you should be able to edit it from there.

Answer (score 0):

As Stewartside said, change the wp-config.php,

Then change the site_url field in "wp_options" table, Then go to Wordpress Admin > Settings > Click Save Permalink.

Then try to run your site. It will automatically update the changes to .htaccess too.

So hope this works for you.